# error 07a0 reading sector 198560

Tags: centos, debian, installation

I just bought a server and now I want to install the OS.

I got the error `EDD: error 07a0 reading sector 198560` when I try to install debian (latest version). I tried CentOS 6.4 but it wont let me install it as well. (stuck at `loading initrd.img`)

I use OSX disk utility to burn the disks (`cd-r`) at slow speed.

How can I solve this and what cause the problem?

Comment: That's a hard disk error

Answer (score 0):

Your burner might be generating DVDs that are out of alignment.  So try using another Burner.

OR Your DVD reader is reading out stuff and is not in proper alignment.